# Run the Installjammer setup from a script

Tags: installation

I have got stuck with my InstallJammer setup creation. Let me explain what I need.
I have created a template project setup using InstallJammer. I wish to use the same template for all the Projects my team creates. What actually I need is to run the Installjammer setup from a script where I can give the Application name.exe, common path to all the related files including help, readme, licence, jar(exe) and icon. via virtual text or some how to the script. How can I do this?

From where should I start?I already referenced the InstallJammer User guide, but still got no idea of such a matter. Please help as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance to Stack Overflow team.